# Using Powershell to execute script when no more changes have been made to folder

Tags: powershell

I am currently attempting to have my computer monitor a folder and execute a script to process the files within the folder. 
I have a functional script written using python.
I only want to execute the script when no more changes have been made to the folder.

Monitor>wait until no more changes made>execute script

This is my current powershell script:

```
    ### SET FOLDER TO WATCH + FILES TO WATCH + SUBFOLDERS YES/NO
    $watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
    $watcher.Path = "D:\folder_to_monitor"
    $watcher.Filter = "*.tif"
    $watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
    $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  

### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER AN EVENT IS DETECTED
    $action = { $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
                $parentdir = Split-Path $path
                $exptdir = Split-Path $parentdir
                $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
                $logline = "$(Get-Date), $changeType, $path"
                Add-content "D:\log\log.txt" -value $logline
                $scriptpath = "D:\script\import.py"
                $intpath = Join-Path $exptdir -ChildPath "\import.py"
                if (-not (Test-Path $intpath))
                {Copy-Item $scriptpath -Destination $exptdir
                }

              }    
### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED 
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action

    while ($true) {sleep 5}
```

I copy and execute the script into each parent folder as I have not yet figured out how to pass the event directory to my python script.

I could not figure out how to ensure that the script is only executed when no more changes have been made.
I'm thinking that perhaps I could call the get-event list?
Any directions to solve this would be much appreciated!

Comment: How does one know there are no more changes incoming?

Comment: The only way i could think of is to wait for an appropriate amount of time, maybe 5-10mins. For my application, i do not expect changes to be made consistently for more than 10min.

Comment: This is a well-researched problem known as [producer-consumer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem). A simple solution is that the producer finishes its operation by creating a flag file. Consumer then processes files and removes the flag. Producer doesn't start as long as flag file is present.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to implement that. 
Watcher -> observe for file increment
2nd watcher -> observe for stop in file increment -> calls for consumer
consumer -> process files and remove counter